# How to stream mp3 audio from remote url in corona sdk?

Tags: android, iphone, mp3, coronasdk

I am building one AudioBook android application using **corona sdk**. I am stuck with `mp3 streaming`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2010/09/24/it-possible-play-streaming-audio) website
Try this HTML5 code:

```
<head> 
<title>Radio</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, 
width=device-width,    user-scalable=no;"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<style type="text/css"> 
html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }
    body {margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<audio id="audio" controls autoplay src="http://oggvorbis.tb-stream.net:
80/technobase.ogg;"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function() {
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("audio");
audioPlayer.load();
audioPlayer.play();
};
</script> 

</body>
```